# Is it possible to determine the current rendering position in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

i would like to create a conditional keeptogether property depending on the space left on the current page, is it possible to get this value from within a formula field?

my goal is a visual clean report without wasting to much space, i already read about a method where you keep track of your position with a linenumber counter. unfortunately i cant use this approach because my lines vary heavy in height because of a note field which holds from 0 to 25 lines.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to sound like a ridiculous and tedious suggestion, but it's the only way I know of making this work. You'll need to use that process of line counting (basically, keeping a running total of how many lines have been printed) that you heard of with one modification: calculate the number of lines Notes needs by the getting the length of that Notes string and dividing by a pre-determined count, which you'll need to do visually, of how many characters are in a line and make the result the line's line count in the overall formula. It's not going to be exactly right because there is no way to make it exactly right, but it will be close. Does that makes sense or do you need me to go into exact detail of how to do this?

Comment: thx for your response, i understand your approach but the result would not be sufficient (varieing text-size, word wrap and so on). i already gave up on my initial idea.